# What is the correct order for recursive queries using two tables on SQL?

Tags: sql, database, recursive-query

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE empleados (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  gerenteId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (gerenteId) REFERENCES empleados(id)
);

CREATE TABLE ventas (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  empleadoId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  valorOrden INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (empleadoId) REFERENCES empleados(id)
);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(1, 'Roberto', null);
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(2, 'Tomas', null);
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(3, 'Rogelio', 1);
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(4, 'Victor', 3);
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(5, 'Johnatan', 4);
INSERT INTO empleados(id, nombre, gerenteId) VALUES(6, 'Gustavo', 2);

INSERT INTO ventas(id, empleadoId, valorOrden) VALUES(1, 3, 400);
INSERT INTO ventas(id, empleadoId, valorOrden) VALUES(2, 4, 3000);
INSERT INTO ventas(id, empleadoId, valorOrden) VALUES(3, 5, 3500);
INSERT INTO ventas(id, empleadoId, valorOrden) VALUES(4, 2, 40000);
INSERT INTO ventas(id, empleadoId, valorOrden) VALUES(5, 6, 3000);
```

I'm trying to get a query to obtain the sum of all the "Orders" which belong directly or inderectly to the main managers. The main managers are the ones whose doesn't report to anybody else. In this calse, Roberto and Tomas are the main managers but there could be other ones. The result must to take into account not just the sales (ventas) made directly by him but also by any of their employees (direct employees or employees of their employees).

So in this case I'm expecting the following result:

```
-- Id    TotalVentas
-- ----------------
-- 1     6900               
-- 2     43000
```

Where the Id column refers to the employees' id which are "main" managers and TotalVentas column is the sum of all the ventas (valorOrden) made by them and their employees.

So Roberto has no records for orders but Rogelio (his employee) has one of 400, Victor (Rogelio's employee) has one for 3000 and Johnatan (Victor's employee) has another for 3500. So the sum of all of them is 6900. And it is the same case with Tomas which has one venta directly made by him plus another one made by Gustavo who is his employee.

The query that I have so far is the following:

```
WITH cte_org AS (
    SELECT       
        id, 
        nombre,
        gerenteId,
        0 as EmpLevel
        
    FROM       
        dbo.empleados
    WHERE gerenteId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        e.id, 
        e.nombre,
        e.gerenteId,
        o.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM 
        dbo.empleados e
        INNER JOIN cte_org o 
            ON o.id = e.gerenteId
        WHERE e.gerenteId IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT cte.id, SUM(s.orderValue)
FROM cte_org cte, dbo.sales s
WHERE (cte.id = s.employeeId AND cte.gerenteId is null)
        OR
        (cte.id = s.employeeId AND cte.EmpLevel <> 0 AND
            cte.gerenteId in (select ee.id from dbo.empleados ee where ee.gerenteId is null)
        )
        --AND 
        --(cte.gerenteId in (select ee.id from dbo.empleados ee where ee.gerenteId is null)
        --OR
        --cte.gerenteId is null)
        
--AND cte.gerenteId = NULL
group by cte.id
;
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: ventas, is that the same table as sales?

Comment: The query doesn't match the two given tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @jarlh ventas is sales, sorry for the wrong name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is traversing a hierarchy, starting with the highest level managers, and then joining in the sales:

```
with cte as (
      select id, nombre, id as manager
      from empleados e
      where gerenteid is null
      union all
      select e.id, e.nombre, cte.manager
      from cte join
           empleados e
           on cte.id = e.gerenteid
     )
select cte.manager, sum(valororden)
from cte join
     ventas v
     on cte.id = v.empleadoid
group by cte.manager;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b059386ee8f753ccef6d1ed9c962ed96) is a db<>fiddle.  The Fiddle uses SQL Server, because that is consistent with the syntax that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can do this using below query:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99df0/12)

```
  select manager, sum(amount) as total_amount from 
(
select level, CONNECT_BY_ROOT employeeid Manager, a.* from 
  (
  SELECT a.id as employeeid, a.nombre as name , a.GERENTEID as manager_id, 
  b.EMPLEADOID as sales_id, b.VALORORDEN amount 
   from empleados a left outer join ventas b
  on (a.id = b.empleadoId)
  ) a
start with manager_id is null
connect by prior employeeid = manager_id) x 
group by manager;
```